# How to get Stripe payments unique identifier to save in database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I am building a site that allows a user to upload one file to my site after making a payment. How can I get a unique identifier, token, id, whatever from Stripe so that I can save in my database?

The identifier has to be unique; I want to use it as a security measure to run `if` statements making sure the user paid before allowing them to upload.

Something like:

```php
if ($newfile->stripe_identifier === $stripe_identifier) {
    // Allow the user to upload
}
```

Comment: I suppose you could associate your file with a Stripe Charge, e.g. `$ch->id` when making a Charge request (`ch_xxxyyyyyzzz`)? https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create

Answer (score 0):

You might use [Laravel Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/billing#simple-charge) for this case.

I think this is the response/JSON object that we got back after a successful charge:

*[The charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object?lang=php)*

I am going to define a payment model and make it a one-to-one relationship with the user:

```
class User
{
    public function payment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Payment::class);
    }
}
```

You may charge the user this way:

```
try {
    $response = $user->charge(100);

    // Persist the response object for later use.
    $user->payment()->create([
        'stripe_id' => $response->id,
        'status' => $response->status,
    ]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //
}
```

Later on when the user is actually uploading the file:

```
FilesController
{
    public function store()
    {
        abort_unless(
            optional(auth()->user()->payment)->status === 'paid',
            402,
            "Please pay before uploading a file."
        );


        // Proceed uploading the file.
    }
}
```

That's the basic idea.